# How to load page views like header, sidebar, footer in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

Im trying to create my second web application in CodeIgniter.

In my previous project I created views for page header, footer and sidebar.

In every page controller I had to load these views like this:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('home'); // home
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('about'); // about
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('contact'); // contact
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

I don't like this and I feel im doing it wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in advance, you can through this way to build your view:

**first** create an Template in your view folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <meta content="MajidGolshadi" name="author">
    <?php echo $html_head; ?>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <?php echo $html_footer; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**second**
create an library to load your view automaticaly

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template
{
    private $data;
    private $js_file;
    private $css_file;
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');

        // default CSS and JS that they must be load in any pages

        $this->addJS( base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js') );
        $this->addCSS( base_url('assets/css/semantic.min.css') );
    }

    public function show( $folder, $page, $data=null, $menu=true )
    {
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/'.$folder.'/'.$page.'.php' ) )
        {
            show_404();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['page_var'] = $data;
            $this->load_JS_and_css();
            $this->init_menu();

            if ($menu)
                $this->data['content'] = $this->CI->load->view('template/menu.php', $this->data, true);
            else
                $this->data['content'] = '';

            $this->data['content'] .= $this->CI->load->view($folder.'/'.$page.'.php', $this->data, true);
            $this->CI->load->view('template.php', $this->data);
        }
    }

    public function addJS( $name )
    {
        $js = new stdClass();
        $js->file = $name;
        $this->js_file[] = $js;
    }

    public function addCSS( $name )
    {
        $css = new stdClass();
        $css->file = $name;
        $this->css_file[] = $css;
    }

    private function load_JS_and_css()
    {
        $this->data['html_head'] = '';

        if ( $this->css_file )
        {
            foreach( $this->css_file as $css )
            {
                $this->data['html_head'] .= "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=".$css->file.">". "\n";
            }
        }

        if ( $this->js_file )
        {
            foreach( $this->js_file as $js )
            {
                $this->data['html_head'] .= "<script type='text/javascript' src=".$js->file."></script>". "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    private function init_menu()
    {        
      // your code to init menus
      // it's a sample code you can init some other part of your page
    }
}
```

**third**
load your library in every controller constructor and then use this lib to load you view automatically

to load additional js in your view you can use `addJS` method in this way:

```
$this->template->addJS("your_js_address");
```

for Css:

```
$this->template->addCSS("your_css_address");
```

and to show your page content call your view file with `show` method

```
$this->template->show("your_view_folder", "view_file_name", $data);
```

i hope this codes help you

Comment: I think you should strip down your code to the bare essentials, but yes, this is the best solution. I used to jury-rig a similar solution in MY_Controller, but this is better.

Answer (score 3):

create template.php in view put this code into this

```
 <?php  
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view($middle);
    $this->load->view('footer');    
?>
```

in controller use this code

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['middle'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could load the header,sidebar, footer in a main template file that you use.

```
// contact.html
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>
<p>Yak yak yak</p>
<?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
```

Or use a template library like [this one](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/)

Comment: Thats even worst than mine, it's less clear. In my code I have everything in one file, but copied over few functions. I don't like copying this to few separate files.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a library (or helper) like so:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View_lib{

   function __construct(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
   }


   function load_view($current_page){
       $parts = array('header', 'sidebar', $current_page, 'footer');
       foreach($parts as $part){
       $this->CI->load->view($part);
    }
   }    
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('view_lib'); // probably better autoload this
    $this->view_lib->load_view('about');
}
```

Kind of barebones, but you get the idea...

Comment: Interesting, but I may need to implement parametrized views handling somehow.

Comment: You can add in `$data`to the `load_view`function rather easily as a second parameter. Then in your foreach check if `$part`== `$current_page`, if so `$this->CI->load->view($part, $data);`. In controller you just add `$data`as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add these files in constructors

```
function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->view('prots/header');
        $this->load->view('prots/top');
        $this->load->view('prots/navigation');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Place all of them in a file like 
main.php

And load it on top of view rather than always sending from controller.

main.php contain 
<php 
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('sidebar');
$this->load->view('home');
$this->load->view('footer');
?>

and in view just place

<php 
$this->load->view('main');
?>

at top of file
```